# Kendo Grid Drag & Drop Destination is undefined

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, drag-and-drop, kendo-grid

I am implementing the kendo Grid drag and drop functionality by using this reference www.jsfiddle.net/JBeQn/

Everything is working fine but when I do drag and drop and on drop event I am getting error of **dest is undefined** I am not sure why this happening I am using latest version of kendo and jQuery.

```
grid.table.kendoDropTarget({
group: "gridGroup",
drop: function(e) {        
    e.draggable.hint.hide();
    var target = dataSource.getByUid($(e.draggable.currentTarget).data("uid")),
        dest = $(document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY));

    if (dest.is("th")) {
        return;
    }       
    dest = dataSource.getByUid(dest.parent().data("uid"));

    //not on same item
    if (target.get("id") !== dest.get("id")) {
        //reorder the items
        var tmp = target.get("position");
        target.set("position", dest.get("position"));
        dest.set("position", tmp);

        dataSource.sort({ field: "position", dir: "asc" });
    }                
}
```

});

Any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dest was null because the method of getByUid wants unique data-uid which created dynamically by kendo grid.

And you can see the code

```
dest.parent()
```

Make sure dest.parent should reach to the tr element where further dest.parent().data("uid") will read UID from tr

Hope this will help to others